# How to get all arguments passed in a function?

Tags: r

Is there a way to "access" all passed arguments in a function? I beleive this can be done i javascript through the *arguments* array, is there an equivalent in R?

```
myfunc <- function() {
    print(arguments[1])
    print(arguments[2])
}

R> myfunc("A","B")

[1] "A"
[1] "B"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, your function has no arguments, so passing arguments to it is an error.

That said, at minimum you would need `...`.  If you do that, you can use `list` on `...` and then access the names of your *copy* of `...`.  For example:

```
myfunc <- function(...) {
  names(list(...))
}
```

Another approach would be to parse the call with `match.call`.  For example:

```
myfunc <- function(A, B) {
  names(match.call()[-1])
}
```